# how can Weblogic 403-Forbidden error can be resolved

Tags: authentication, servlets, weblogic, web.xml

how can i configure it as i am new to servlets kindly help me or let me know if there's a another way.

```
   package com.test;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet  {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException,IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String n = request.getParameter("Username");
    out.print("Welcome"+n);


    }

  }
```

This is my java file 
      package com.test;

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   public class Login extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException,IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();


    String n = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String p = request.getParameter("UserPass");


    if(p.equals("Servlet")){

        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Servlet");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    else{

         out.print("sorry Wrong Password");
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
         rd.include(request, response);

       }


       }

      }
```

this my web.xml file

```
        <web-app>  
        <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>com.test.Login</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
   <servlet>  
   <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.test.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>  


   <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>  
   </servlet-mapping>  
   <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/servlet2</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  
    </web-app>
```

this is my html file

```
             <form action="servlet1" method="post">  
              Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/>  
             Password:<input type="password" name="userPass"/><br/>  
             <input type="submit" value="login"/>  
           </form>
```

Comment: Somthing is called authentication is required.

Comment: yes , i have configured the server but when ever i try to open in local host it is showing me 403 error